# Decompose a vector in 3 vectors

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics, physics

I have an object moving with speed **v**. The object have a **forward**, **right** and **up** vectors (and **v** doesnt need to be in forward direction). All of them are perpendicular to each other.

How can I decompose **v** on these 3 vectors? Mathematically, how can I define **a**, **b** and **c** such that:

```
v = a * forward + b * right + c * up
```

For example, if **v** is very similar to **forward**, **a** should have the biggest value.

Comment: you're looking for the dot product between vectors, see `Vector3.Dot()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko)'s comment is getting at, use [`Vector3.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html):

```
Vector3 a =  Vector3.Dot(v, forward);
Vector3 b =  Vector3.Dot(v, right);
Vector3 c =  Vector3.Dot(v, up);
```

Make sure that `forward`, `right`, and `up` are normalized. That should already be the case if you're using `transform.forward`, `transform.right`, and `transform.up`.

Anyway, if they're not already normalized, use `forward.normalized`, `right.normalized`, and `up.normalized` instead.